# How to add multiple pattern in html input text

Tags: html

How to use multiple pattern in html text input. So that,user can input 1 digit, 2 digit or 3 digit numbers.

1:add '|' between each pattern

```
<input type="text" name="id" id="id" maxlength="3" pattern="\d{1}|\d{2}|\d{3}" required>
```

Result: Able to input one digit number only

2: add '|' between each pattern and bracket for each pattern

```
<input type="text" name="id" id="id" maxlength="3" pattern="(\d{1})|(\d{2})|(\d{3})" required>
```

Result: Able to input one digit number only

Comment: Have you tried `\d{1,3}`?

Comment: I just tried, it works..Is it saying that 1 to 3 digits..range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use range regex instead of exact number match. So in your case it would be `\d{1,3}`

In RegEx there is range selector `{m,n}`.

From 1 to 3: `\d{1,3}`
From 2 to any: `\d{2,}`